# yank full filename to clipboard

Tags: vifm

hi i am using vifm on windows and really liking it. I have put this on `vifmrc` file to yank full filename to clipboard -

```
nnoremap yf :!echo %d\%c%i| clip<cr>
```

It works fine, but if the filename or path contains `space` character, the command escapes it which breaks the full path.

for example -

```
actual path: d:\work documents\file name with space.txt

yanked path: d:\work\ documents\file\ name\ with\ space.txt
```

can anyone tell me how to fix it to avoid the escaping?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the correct result using the following mapping instead -

```
nnoremap yf :!pwsh -c "\"%d\%c%i\".Replace(\"\ \",\" \")"| clip<cr>
```

It invokes powershell script and replaces "\ " with " " then pipes the result to `clip`